# onBackPressed with extend Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with android studio which extends to AppCompatActivity:

```js
public class Act_1 extends AppCompatActivity {
```

And the onBackPressed event works great.

```js
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
        
 }
```

This same event I wish to use in an activity that extends to Fragment:

```js
public class Act_2 extends Fragment{
```

But when I write the code, there is an error message about @Override that says:

"Method does not override method from its superclass"

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Act_2 is not an `Activity`, is a `Fragment` and the  `onBackPressed()` method is an `Activity's` method, so you cannot override it in your `Fragment`. To fix this issue change your Act_2 to extend `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed` is under `Activity` not `Fragment`. What you can do is override the method in `Activity`.

Like this::

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =
   getSupportFragmentManager();
int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

if (count > 0) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
} else {
    if (this instanceof HomeActivity) {
        //additional code
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```